# Keras regression multiple outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, keras

a question concerning keras regression with multiple outputs:

Could you explain the difference beteween this net:

two inputs -> two outputs

```
input = Input(shape=(2,), name='bla')
hidden = Dense(hidden, activation='tanh', name='bla')(input)
output = Dense(2, activation='tanh', name='bla')(hidden)
```

and: two single inputs -> two single outputs:

```
input = Input(shape=(2,), name='speed_input')
hidden = Dense(hidden_dim, activation='tanh', name='hidden')(input)
output = Dense(1, activation='tanh', name='bla')(hidden)

input_2 = Input(shape=(1,), name='angle_input')
hidden_2 = Dense(hidden_dim, activation='tanh', name='hidden')(input_2)
output_2 = Dense(1, activation='tanh', name='bla')(hidden_2)

model = Model(inputs=[speed_input, angle_input], outputs=[speed_output, angle_output])
```

They behave very similar. Other when I completly seperate them, then the two nets behave like they re supposed to.

And is it normal that two single output nets behave much more intelligible than a bigger one with two outputs, I didnt think the difference could be huge like I experienced.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

This goes back to how neural networks operate. In your first model, each hidden neuron receives 2 input values (as it is a 'Dense' layer, the input propagates to every neuron). In your second model, you have twice as many neurons, but each of these only receive either `speed_input` or `angle_input`, and only works with that data instead of the entire data.

So, if `speed_input` and `angle_input` are 2 completely unrelated attributes, you'll likely see better performance from splitting the 2 models, since neurons aren't receiving what is basically noise input (they don't know that your outputs correspond to your inputs, they can only try to optimize your loss function). Essentially, you're creating 2 seperate models.

But in most cases, you want to feed the model relevant attributes that combine to draw a prediction. So splitting the model then would not make sense, since you're just stripping neccessary information away.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time :) 

So Keras does completly seperate this two nets in the second example? Where is the difference between two seperetly build and learned nets (in two different scripts) and this option?

Comment: To answer your first question, no, not really. Both nets are still in the same Model object, but computationally they're completely unrelated.

Comment: The difference to having 2 different Model objects is that now you have to train them at the same time and with the same number of examples. On one hand, it's kind of inconvenient. But let's say if your problem always requires the output of both networks, you can actually save time and memory by having them train and run side-by-side.